# Animate both width and height on click with jQuery

Tags: jquery, height, width, jquery-animate

Trying to animate both the width and the height of these boxes on click.

See fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/CqDXn/1/

I've been successful with getting the width to animate... no just need to prevent that awkward jump at the end of the animation.

edit:

worth noting I cannot set a static height on the li's

Answer (score 1):

- What's 200? in em? px? use a measurement. '200px'.
- You didn't animate the height as well as the width: {width: '200px', height: '200px'}
- I dropped the .active css rule for auto height. The animation needs to take care of that.

code:

```
$(document).delegate('.rewards-process li:not(.active)', 'click', function(e)
    {
        var toActive = $(this);
        $('.rewards-process li.active').addClass('transition');
        $('.rewards-process li.active').animate({
            width:'90px'
            , height: '90px'},1000,function() {
                $('.rewards-process li.active').removeClass('active').removeClass('transition');
            });

$(toActive).animate({
    width:'200px'
    , height: '200px'},300,function(){
        //animation complete
        $(toActive).addClass('active')
    });

});
```

I sometimes use this hack for figuring out a dynamic height:

```
function getElementHeight(e, width) {
 $("body").append("<div id='test' style='width:" + width + "'>" + e.html() + "</div>").hide();
    var h = e.outerHeight();
    e.remove();
    return h;
}
```

You need to make sure the CSS doesn't mess this up.

Basically you create the element with the final width, calculate its height and then remove it. This function will return a number, you'll need to add `px` and you can use it in your animation.

**But** you don't really need this. Height animates automatically for you, your CSS rules just disabled it. For example, [this fiddle will work just fine](http://jsfiddle.net/qQh4p/).

Comment: Hey Radagaisus, thanks for your help! Unfortunately, I cant set a static height for the li's to grow to because I dont know what the content will be

Comment: There are several methods to do that. I'm adding them to my answer.

Comment: Appreciate the help, I'll need to rework how I am hiding and showing content (onclick, content with a class of active gets display: block as of right now). But great advice, good to know jQuery will do this for me if I just fix my method. thanks a lot

Comment: It's not jQuery. It's plain old css and browser rendering.

Comment: I meant that jQuery will animate the height for me... The reason I can't just use your fiddle fix (http://jsfiddle.net/qQh4p/ ) is because content hides and shows on click as well

Comment: Radagaisus in jQ if you use .animate() you don't need measurements if you plan to animate in PX. You HAVE to use measurements only if you use the .css() method

Answer (score 0):

To animate the height, just add a height value under the width in the animate call.

That jump at the end is caused by the browser trying to automatically re-layout all the elements. In order to prevent that, you should put them all into a grid, then re-layout the grid each time the animation finishes.

Comment: ok, I hear what youre saying about the browser trying to re-layout all the elements. I cant add height: '200px' though because I'm not sure what content will go in the containers...so no set height. Maybe I collect the height of the tallest element and then add it to the animation... hmm

Comment: Use the jQuery .height() method to collect the heights before hand, then use that to fill in the height value.

Answer (score 0):

This line on your css is causing the jump.

```
.rewards-process .active img, .rewards-process .active p {display:block; }
```

Try removing the "display:block" property and it should went smoothly. Find a way to have a remedy for that element. It should be easy.

Comment: actually on this selector only ".rewards-process .active p"